# How can I insert text in middle of a document and have images move down too?

Tags: macos, mac, pages

I have a document with text and floating images. Let's say I want to insert some text in the middle of the document. If i click in the document and hit enter a bunch of times, I want the existing text and images to slide down so I can put my new content there, but only the text moves down and the images don't.

How can I make it so everything would slide down when I press enter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use inline objects that cause text to be wrapped:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have text alongside the images by choosing "Object Causes Wrap" and then selecting one of the left three options. I don't know how the default is chosen, but it sometimes chooses one of the right two options, both of which keep it clear on either side of an object.

You can also move floating objects in a long document by using Section Breaks (under the insert menu). These act like page breaks, but keep text and floating images together within a section, so a change on page one only affects images in that section. It is not perfect, but it is better than the alternative.

If you really want to control things, bite the bullet and use Page Layout mode when you create a new document. You can set up linked text boxes where text rows around images that are fixed to a page.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have *floating* images.
If you select them and press the *inline* button in the toolbar, they will also move down when you insert content on above them.

Comment: I don't want them to be inline though because I want text along side the images. Must not be anyway to do this.

Comment: So you want them to be floating and not floating at the same time?

Comment: @patrix :) It seems so!

Comment: I spose that is what I want....

Comment: So if I have a 100 page document and need to insert a few words in the beginning and it misaligns everything, I have to move every single picture down just a little bit?